# Динамический Resource в Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Скажите пожалуйста как мне сделать динамические Маркеры на Google Maps? Динамичность заключается в том, что картинка может быть любого цвета, любой формы и с любым текстом. В принципе можно сделать таких картинок на каждую букву и впихнуть в папку с ресурсами и потом грузить ту которая пригодится, но это костыль :(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]